How can I share a node.s backend between web and mobile?
My pages are like this
Server => Nodejs APIs
Client => React
Mobile => React Native

On mobile, should I make requests to nodejs like I do with react? I don't need to make any type of change to the requests? because when I call an endpoint in react native, I get the following error:

possible unhandled promise rejection (id 0) typeerror network request failed


just use a fetch request to send a request to backend.
for example
const res = await fetch("http://localhost:8080/api/v1/users");
const data = await res.json();

// use the data.

make sure you user "http://10.0.2.2:8080" for react native in development.
